# visual studio code display crash

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image: my visual studio code display]

has anyone ever experienced a visual studio code look like this ?
I have tried removing the extension and even reinstalling it with the latest version but it still looks like this.
only in this application it looks like this. my laptop vga has no problem. open any application looks good. My vga driver is the latest.

Comment: No idea but try removing all extensions and restarting Visual Studio Code

Comment: already done, but it still looks the same. not successful